# Error loading the CAM PPA while Installing Cloud Automation Manager offline

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-automation-manager

Trying to register the Cloud Automation Manager offline PPA image into IBM Cloud Private with the command: bx pr load-helm-chart --archive ibm-cam-prod-1.2.0.tgz

fails with following error:

Returned status 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible resolutions:

1) Mostly this error occurs due to incomplete download,  double check the md5sum for ibm-cam-prod-1.2.0.tgz

2) Run the following commands prior to try the bx pr load-helm-chart command:

bx pr login -a https://mycluster.icp:8443 --skip-ssl-validation
docker login mycluster.icp:8500

3) The error could be caused by ICP plugin to bx that is old.  Can you display the version info with ‘bx plugin list’.

The successful version for the plugin is :

bx plugin list

Listing installed plug-ins...

Plugin Name   Version

icp           2.1.182

Try to update the plugin as documented here :https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0.2/manage_cluster/install_cli.html

Answer (score 2):

If your ICP envirnment has access to the internet you can also avoid all this by using the online install option.

This is new in CAM 2.1.0.2 and you can see the steps to use it here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_2.1.0.2/cam_install_EE_online.html